# Verilog changing a value of a variable

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am implementing a simple counter which is counting the number of time  push buttons are pressed. I wrote the following code:

```
module lock(
anodes,cathodes,leds,
sw,btns,clk );

//input declarations
input[7:0] sw;
input[3:0]btns;
input clk;


always @(curbtns)
begin
if( prevbtns!=0 && curbtns==0)
begin
    counter_next = counter + 5'b00001;
end
else
    counter_next = counter;
prevbtns = curbtns;
end


always @(btns or sw)
begin
case(btns)
4'b0001:curbtns=4'b0001;
4'b0010:curbtns=4'b0010;
4'b0100:curbtns=4'b0100;
4'b1000:curbtns=4'b1000;
4'b0000:curbtns=4'b0000;
default:curbtns = prevbtns; 
endcase
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
counter <=counter_next;
create_slow_clock(clk,slow_clock);
end
endmodule
```

When I simulate the above code in icraus verilog it seems to be working but on actual FPGA my counter is not changing. Is there any problem in the logic of incrementing the variable.

Updated code(Working)

```
always @(curbtns or prevbtns or counter)
begin
 if( prevbtns!=0 && curbtns==0)
 begin
 counter_next = counter + 5'b00001;
 end
 else
 counter_next = counter;
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
counter <=counter_next;
prevbtns <=curbtns;
create_slow_clock(clk,slow_clock);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look to be missing some signals in your sensitivity lists for the combinational always blocks.

For your code to be properly synthesizable, a combinational block must be sensitive to **every** input signal.

The first always block `always @(curbtns)` needs to be sensitive to `prevbtns`, `curbtns`, and `counter`.

The second block `always @(btns or sw)` also needs to be sensitive to `prevbtns` (I don't see `sw` used in this block anyway, should get rid of it).

I recommend changing both blocks to `always @*`, so that the lists may be automatically inferred, and it's not a fragile point of breakage if you change the logic and forget to change the list.

Comment: Yes, my Xilinix is giving me warning about the sensitivity list. But if I add prevbtns to always block with curbtns, wouldn't it produce a loop because I am assigning prevbtns in that always block?

Comment: Yes you are right. However note that you've designed a loop into the block by using `prevbtns!=0` as one of your inputs. It seems to me that prevbtns needs to be changed to a clocked register to remove the feedback loop. You can't have any feedback in a purely combinational block.

Comment: Yeah, now I am getting the meaning of what I read somewhere that using a variable in a "if" statement is like using it in the right hand side of the expression. So now I need to somehow move "prevbtns" out of the always block. But now another thing which I am concerned about if I set "prevbtns" in some other block, how will I ensure the synchronization between these two blocks??

Comment: `prevbtns` should be latched, there is no synchronization issue. `always @(posedge clk) prevbtns <= curbtns;`. On every positive edge clock the value of prevbtns and counter is saved, and then these retained values (in conjunction with the inputs), allow the derivation of the new value of curbtns. Then there is no combinational feedback and everybody should be happy. If you're still confused please try to describe what you think the problem would be and I'll be happy to clear it up. @Manish

Comment: I have updated the code(though only one line needed to be moved) and it is working also. What I meant with synchronization is that in my opinion my "prevbtn" must be updated only after  the condition "if( prevbtns!=0 && curbtns==0)" has been executed. How we are achieving this by setting the "prevbtns"  at the +ve clock and non-blockin assignment?

Comment: `prevbtn` update will always happen after the combinational block has executed, because the comb. block executes instantly, and prevbtn always updates on the next clock edge. Assume for a moment that the clock has just risen, and all of your registers have a stable value. Once your registers have a new value, the combinational block executes due to the inputs changing, and then it computes a stable output value based on the inputs. Then some time later (one clock period), prevbtn samples the new value of currbtn and the sequence repeats. @Manish

Comment: As long as your design meets *static timing analysis* (a whole other topic), it's guaranteed that the combinational blocks can finish executing before the next rising edge of the clock.

Comment: Ok..Just one more doubts. What would the situation have been if I want my "prevbtn"to be updated before the condition? If I am right then it must be placed in some "combinational block"?

Comment: That doesn't make too much sense to me, it's a cyclical thing. Prevbutton always updates before and after the comb. logic in an infinite cycle: *posedge clk, prevbtn updates, comb. logic updates, posedge clk, prevbtn updates, comb. logic updates, posedge clk, prevbtn updates, comb. logic updates, etc...* I'm not quite grasping what you mean. @Manish

Comment: :Ohh..it's fine now..Thanks for your useful comments.